# Join() call is freezing the execution while I create process with multyprocessing module

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, queue, multiprocessing

I am making some tests by using multiprocessing functions and I am facing to a freezing issue after calling join function.

```
import time
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock, Value

def writeDF(start,end,td,lock,q):
    print('write from ',start,' ',end)
    for  i in range(start,end):
        lock.acquire()
        q.put(td.iloc[i,:])
        lock.release()
    print('function writeDF completed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    td=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\dorian\Desktop\Analyzer.txt', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", index_col="Start", parse_dates=True, sep=',')
    td=td[0:10] 
    jobs=[]
    q = Queue()
    lock = Lock()


    start = time.time()

    begin=0
    stop=td.shape[0]/2

    for i in range(0,2):
        if len(jobs) < 10:
            t = Process(target=writeDF, args=(int(begin),int(stop),td, lock,q))
            t.start()
            jobs.append(t)
            begin=stop
            stop=stop+(td.shape[0]/2)
        else:    
            t = jobs.pop(0)
            t.join()

    for p in jobs: 
        print('try to join element:',p)
        p.join()
        print('element is join')

    l=[]    
    while not q.empty():
        l.append(q.get())

    df=pd.DataFrame(l)
    end = time.time()  
    print('Value:',df.shape)
    print('2 process Time taken in seconds -', end - start)
```

Actual Result is that the program is freezing on the join() statement however since the start () is before the join() it should not be blocked

Answer (score 0):

`multiprocessing.Queue` queues have a capacity limited by the underlying OS-level pipes used to implement them. That means you can't wait for the writers to finish before reading. Writers and readers *must* execute concurrently to safely use a `multiprocessing.Queue`. You're not doing that.

Comment: Right it was the root cause of this freeze. I have updated the code such as writers and readers are executed in parallels. I have one more question when I create a process with objects as parameters of my target the new process make a copy of the objects. Is there a way to share a reference of my objects between process ?